# Get content from the folder on ftp server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the content of the folders on the ftp server.
    I am calling the asp page that is on the ftp path. But the page content is shown only when I login to the admin section and the content is not shown when its not logged in. 
    Can anyone tell me how can I get all the contents on the web page from the ftp server path?

Following is my code-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var message;
    function testAjax() {   
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/v/vspfiles/admin/View_Category.asp",
            data: "{}",
            success: function(data) {
                message = $('<div ></div>').append(data).find('.rightsection .cat').text();
            }
        });
    }
    function displayData(x) {
        x.success(function(realData) {
            $('#file_content').append(message);
        });
    } 
    var promise = testAjax();
    displayData(promise);
});
```

Please advice.

Comment: This is not really a Javascript issue, is it? You will need to first try and create an API on your server that returns the directory's listing. Stack Overflow is not meant to provide you with solutions to problems you haven't even begun to attempt to resolve on your own.

Comment: Maybe the url `/v/vspfiles/admin/View_Category.asp` tells why. It's part of the `admin` folder, which more than likely requires admin login credentials, no?